# Optimizing MySQL table for selecting many rows in date range

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, innodb

I have an InnoDB table in MySQL where I have to select and sum a lot of data in date ranges. It seems I can't get to a point where it runs fast enough for the use case.

The table is as follows:
user_id: int
date: date
amount: int

The table has several hundred million rows.
A date range can return up to 10 million rows.
Amount is 1-10

I have a composite index on all three columns in the order: user_id, date, amount.

The query I use for selecting is:

```
SELECT   
    SUM(amount)  
FROM table  
WHERE user_id = ?  
AND request_date <= ?  
AND request_date >= ?
```

I hardcode the dates into the query.

Anything else I can do to speed up this query? I should be able to do the query about 20 times a second.

It's running on DI with 8gb RAM and 4 CPUs (not dedicated).

**Update**
The output of EXPLAIN is:

```
select_type: SIMPLE  
type: range
possible_keys: composite  
key: composite  
key_len: 7 
ref: null 
rows: 14994440  
Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Comment: Can you please post the output from EXAPLIN? (pre-pend the word EXPLAIN to the query above)

Comment: Added update with the output of EXPLAIN

Comment: Partition the table.  Are date ranges you search for spanning years, decades? what? You could go as far to partition by user and year if needed.  That way the hundres of millions of rows are far fewer.

Comment: The range is 30 days. But 30 days running from current date. So I can’t partition for specific months. There can still be up to 10 million rows per user for a 30 period, times a few hundred users.

Comment: @xQbert - He still has to touch all the rows for that user in that date range.  So no benefit to partitioning.

Comment: Note that it says "Using index".  This means that the entire query was performed in the BTree for that index.

Comment: Seems odd that this article touts a 90% gain; but maybe because it lacked an index. http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html

Comment: @xQbert - Yeah.  I find that judicious changes to the indexes are almost always needed when switching to (or from) partitioning.  After years of searching, I have come up with only 4 use cases for partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: @xQbert - In particular, if he had added `INDEX(date)` to the non-partitioned version, it, too, would have run in about 3.8 seconds!  The 90% is marketing hype presented back when Partitioning was added (more than a decade ago).

Answer (score 3):

I've used various techniques in the past to do similar stuff.

- You should consider partitioning your table. That involves creating a column that contains a partition identifier, which could be a date, or year-month
- I've had some performance increase by splitting the date and time portion. The advantage is that you can then quickly grab all data from a date by looking at the `date` field, without even considering the time portion.
- If you know what kind of data you'll be requesting, and you can allow for some delays, you can pre-calculate. It looks like you're working with log-data, so I assume that query results for anything that's older than today will never change. You should exploit that, for example by having a separate table with aggregated data. If you only need to calculate "today" things will be much faster. Or accept that numbers are a bit old, you can just pre-calculate periodically.

The table that I'm talking about could be something like:

```
CREATE table aggregated_requests AS
SELECT user_id, request_date, SUM(amount) as amount
FROM table
```

After that, rewrite your query above like this, and i'll be extremely fast:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)  
FROM aggregated_requests  
WHERE user_id = ?  
AND request_date <= ?  
AND request_date >= ?
```

Comment: Thanks! You’re right - It’s logging, for rate limitting. The issue I’m facing with some of your solutions is that I’m not querying for a specific month, but 30 days running. It doesn’t make it impossible, just a bit more challenging.

Comment: So if you partition by year and month you'd cut your records your looking at from hundreds of millions to hundreds of thousands and perhaps millions.  at worst you'd be looking at 2 partitions if looking at a 30 day moving range.

Comment: I’ll give it a try. The reason for asking the question here is that I’m unsure if the biggest problem is the total amount of data or the amount of rows I’m summing up.

Comment: @stromgen: biggest improvement opportunity here is to to make use of the fact that even though you write constantly, most of the data is static. Think of it like this: if you have 100 days of data in your table, that at any time only 1% ("today") will be dynamic. The older days will always have a same sum. So just calculate that once, and recall the result whenever you need it, instead of querying the entire data over and over again.

Comment: Those perceived benefits of `PARTITIONing` are bogus.  Keep in mind that picking the partition is sort of like descending one level of a BTree -- a wash.

Comment: @Stromgren - It is the number of rows summing up.  Your composite index already makes that as efficient as possible.  Partitioning will _not_ help.

Comment: @RickJames Any other suggestions? I’ll probably have to run a process that sums the data up in another table and accept eventual consistency.

Comment: @Rick James: I don't want to discard your point about indexes, but you CAN improve speed dramatically using partitioning if you have huge tables, especially when you stripe your data over different physical drives. I've used it several times, and we did extensive tests before doing it. But in this case, pre-calculating is a much more practical solution, and you can gain much more speed like that.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick - Was that with MySQL?  What speed-up factor did you achieve, with how many disk drives?

Comment: A side note:  MySQL has zero parallelism built in.  Any attempt to tack in on would probably saturate the I/O before coming anywhere near to using all the CPU cores.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  `INDEX(user_id, request_date, amount)`  -- optimal for the WHERE, also "covering".  OK, you have that; so, on to plan B:

Plan B (even better):  Build and maintain a Summary table of, say, daily subtotals.  Then query that table instead.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Partitioning is unlikely to help more than a good index (as in Plan A).

**More on B**

If you need up-to-the-minute totals, there are multiple approaches to achieve it using summary tables without waiting until the next day.

- IODKU against the summary table at the same time (possibly in a Trigger) that you insert the row data.  This keeps the summary table up to date, but with non-trivial overhead.
- Hybrid.  Reach into the summary table for whole days, then total up 'today' from the raw data and add it on.
- Summarize by hour instead of by day.  This either gives you only hourly resolution, or you can combine with the "hybrid" to make that run faster.

(My blog gives those 3, plus 3 more.)

**Other**

"Amount is 1-10" -- I hope you are using a 1-byte `TINYINT`, not a 4-byte `INT`.  That's 300MB of difference.  Perhaps `user_id` could be smaller than `INT`.